# Unable to Authorize org in VSCode. SystemError: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented)

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, command-line-interface, sfdx

Salesforce. Unable to Authorize org in VSCode.
SystemError: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented).

sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias testorg --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
(node:3996) [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR] SystemError Plugin: sfdx-cli [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
module: @oclif/config@1.18.3
task: runHook init
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: C:\Program Files\sfdx\client
See more details with DEBUG=*
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
SystemError: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS
(function not implemented)
Code: ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR

I have unistalled vs-code and re-istalled multiple times. Also uninstaled & re-imstalled sfdc cli as well. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened due to the version of the windows operating system. It gives error in windows 7. It is working fine on higher versions.